# guardar en variables los elementos de una respuesta xml

Tags: xml, vb

Como grabar elementos de lista de un xml?

es decir tengo la respuesta que me regea varios elementos y esos elementos guardarlo en variables?

ejemplo:

```
For Each nd As Xml.XmlNode In record
   rec= New Response()
   rec.nombre = nd.Item("Nombre").InnerText
   rec.direccion = nd.Item("dir").InnerText
   rec.factura = nd.Item("folio").InnerText
   resp.ListaRecord.Add(rec)
Next
```

algo así

Answer (score 0):

Hay una clase denominada Document o XmlDocument en Vb para trabajar con xml. Podrías cargar el xml con algo asi:

```
 Dim xml = new Document
 Xml.loadxml(tu xml aquí)
 Dim nodes as xmlnodes=xml.selectnodes("tu ruta xpath               aquí")
 For i=0 to nodes.count - 1
 Variable=nodes(i)

 Next
```

Disculpa, hace tiempo que no trabajo con Vb. Ahora trabajo con c#. Espero sea de ayuda..

Comment: La clase Document es para trabajar con xml utilizando el DOM (document object model). El contenido del xml se localiza utilizando el sintaxis XPATH con comandos como SelectNodes, p.e. SelectNodes("book/author") en el caso de existir un nodo denominado author debajo del nodo book. En MSDN puedes encontrar ejemplos de lectura de xml con DOM y XPATH. Es dificil contestarte en unas lineas, ya que tiene mucho fondo. Espero sea de ayuda